# How to use same string resource for different item types

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a String called `Products.Label` which is use for an `AppBarButton`. How can I use the same string for a `TextBox` without the app crashing?

**MainPage.xaml**

```
...
<AppBarButton Name="AppBarButtonProducts" x:Uid="Products"/>
...
```

**Settings.xaml**

```
...
<TextBlock x:Uid="Products/Label" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to use same string resource for different item types

You could make x:string [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references) in the application resource  for different control like the following.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="Placeholder">Placeholder Content</x:String>
</Application.Resources>


<TextBox
    Height="44"
    PlaceholderText="dddd"
    Text="{StaticResource Placeholder}"
    />
```

Comment: Which file does <x:String x:Key="Placeholder">Placeholder Content</x:String> need
to be added to?

Comment: You could add the x:string to App.xaml file .

Comment: But if we want those strings to be also localized? How can we combine the multiple languages pattern using x:uid and .resw files and using them on multiple controls at the same time? Because until now I always needed to do it in code-behind... but I want to do as much as possible in XAML. Best regards and thank you for your attention.

Comment: Have checked this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest) that told how to localize string in uwp.